# Scope ajax no funciona laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, scope

Resulta que el query `scope` no funciona, estoy utilizando `ajax` para capturar los datos, me ocurre lo siguiente cuando en el controlador cargo el paginador, la tabla me muestra los registros

```
$dataInsumo = Insumo::orderBy('descripcionIns','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Pero cuando cargo el scope `Buscar`, no muestra ninguno

```
$dataInsumo = Insumo::Buscar($request->scope)->orderBy('descripcionIns','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Adjunto mi `InsumoController`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $dataInsumo = Insumo::Buscar($request->scope)->orderBy('descripcionIns','DESC')->paginate(5);
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(view('insumo.table',compact('dataInsumo'))->render());
    }
    //TUTORIAL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D7CVpUh8vQ
    $titulo1 = 'Mantenimiento de Insumos';
    $tipo = TipoInsumo::all();
    return view('insumo.index')
    ->with(['dataInsumo'=>$dataInsumo])
    ->with('titulo1',$titulo1)
    ->with('tipo',$tipo);
}
```

Adjunto mi modelo `Insumo`

```
public function scopeBuscar($query, $scope=''){
    return $query->where('descripcionIns','LIKE',"%scope%");  
}
```

Adjunto mi `Insumo.js`
Este codigo es para la paginación ajax

```
$(document).on('click','.pagination a',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
var route = 'http://localhost/mshalom/public/insumo';

$.ajax({
    url:route,
    data: {page: page},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        $("#divtable").html(result);
    }
});
});
```

Este codigo captura el valor del texto #scope, probe con un `alert` y me captura el texto

```
$(document).on('click','#btnbuscar',function(e){
var route = 'http://localhost/mshalom/public/insumo';
var scope = $("#scope").val();
$.ajax({
    url:route,
    data: {scope: scope},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        $("#divtable").html(result);
    }
});
});
```

Adjunto mi Vista `Insumo.index`, en el slot `insumo.table` solo cargo la tabla con registros.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"> <!-- Boton Nuevo -->
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ url('insumo/create') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Nuevo Insumo</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 form-horizontal">

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 ">  <!-- Caja de Texto de busqueda -->
    <div class="input-group">
        <!-- Caja de Texto de busqueda -->
        <input id="scope"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite insumo...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <!-- Boton -->
        <button id = "btnbuscar" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 " id="divtable">
@component('insumo.table')
    @slot('dataInsumo',$dataInsumo)
@endcomponent
</div>      
</div>            
    @endsection

   @section('js')
  <script src="{{asset('js/mshalomjs/insumo.js')}}"></script>
  @endsection
```

Muy agradecido quedo de su respuesta de antemano.

Comment: ¿haciendo exactamente la misma búsqueda, sin el scope funciona? ¿has probado con `buscar()` en minúscula?

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu archivo de rutas? o al menos ver las rutas implicadas.

Comment: cacheo la peticion ajax y solo me devuelve la cabecera de la tabla mas no los registros.

Comment: En mi ruta uso resource   Route::resource('/insumo','InsumoController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias, por su ayuda. encontre el error, esta en el modelo

Tenia que declarar la variable scope concatenando con %

```
public function scopeBuscar($query, $scope=''){
return $query->where('descripcionIns','LIKE',"%".$scope."%");  
}
```

Yo la estaba declarando "%$scope%" por ello no me buscaba ningun registro.